# Sending an email with an attachment error - couldn't attach the file

Tags: android

I'm new in sharing in android, but I search more and more on this topic but still, an error message appears when I attach the image URI to send the email:

> couldn't attach file

Here is my  function:

```
private void sharePopup(Uri shortLink) {
    ArrayList<Uri> uris =  new ArrayList<>();
    uris.add( Uri.parse(news.getUrl()));
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,shortLink.toString());
    sendIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uris);
    sendIntent.setType("image/*");
    sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share With..."), ApiKeys.SHARE_REQUEST);
}
```

What is wrong in this function that would cause it not to attach the image to the email?

Comment: did you add permission in manifest file.

Comment: permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,permission.INTERNET,android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE,android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE,
this is all permission i add to  manifest file